# How to get a multilevel object on expression with JsonPath

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

For the current example of store/books on

https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

If the author its a object

```
"author" : { "name" : "Joe", "lastName": "Doe" }
```

How could I get all authors that the lastName is Doe, all examples I saw use just simple objects on arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all authors with last name 'Doe' :

```
$.store.book[*].author[?(@.lastName == 'Doe')]
```

To get all books by authors with last name 'Doe' :

```
$.store.book[?(@.author.lastName == 'Doe')]
```

Comment: I thought the same, but didn't work, maybe i am using an old version of json-path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$..author[?(@.lastName = 'Doe')];
```

Should do it I think. Based on a quick read of the *readme*. The syntax is based on *Xpath*. So it isn't that difficult to comprehend.

- `$` start at root.
- `..` deep scan
- `author` select all author objects.
- `[?(@.lastName = 'Doe')]` search for objects where lastName = `Doe`